# Open workbook, count a range and write count into another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in a Excel workbook and I am performing count operation from different files and update it in the file which has macro.

```
Private Sub count_Click()
    Dim MyCount(1 To 3) As Long
    Dim myData As Workbook
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\cas\Book3.xlsx") ' selecting a workbook'

    With myData.Worksheets("sheet1")
        Set Rng = Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange)
        MyCount(1) = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng)
    End With

    With myData.Worksheets("sheet1")
        Set Rng = Intersect(.Columns(5), .UsedRange)
        MyCount(2) = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng)
    End With

    'MsgBox "count is " & MyCount(1)
    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\cas\Book2.xlsm")
       ' the workbook where I want the values to be transferred'

    With myData.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1")
        .Offset(RowCount, 0) = MyCount(1)
    End With

    With myData.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2")
        .Offset(RowCount, 0) = MyCount(2)
    End With
End Sub
```

I have tried opening the workbook and updating the values, but the values are not displayed.
It is probably because the instance of the workbook is open and it is unable to update.

Comment: are there any error messages? And in which workbook is the procedure `count_Click()`? If it is `Book2.xlsm` then `Set myData = ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it may be open read only you can try:

```
'MsgBox "count is " & MyCount(1)
 Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\cas\Book2.xlsm")

 If myData.ReadOnly Then
    MsgBox "File is Read-only"
    exit sub
 Else
    MsgBox "File is not read-only"
 End If
```

Comment: that's not it. not able to set myData as Book2.